# Semantic urls with dots in .net

Tags: .net, iis, routes

I'm trying to make semantic urls for search pages, but if someone use a search finished in dot, the .net engine return a 404.

The request don't even get to the routing  engine, so i think its something related to security or something like that.

For example, the stackoverflow routes also don't work in these case:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etc.

Comment: Need more info. What exact .NET technology are you using to do the routing? Is this ASP.NET MVC also like stackoverflow.com?

Comment: no, it's castle monorail, but it doesn't matter, as the request don't get into the framework code. I have seen this error in clasic webforms sites, asp.net mvc ones, and monorail ones also. It must be something related with the webserver, but I cant find anything about this in the doc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 and IIS 7+, you can set this flag in the system.web section of your web.config and it will be allowed:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

I've tested it and it works. [Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) has an explanation of it.

Comment: @Roger it requires iis7. I added that to the answer.

Comment: how can you do that in IIS < 7?

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of Windows.

Comment: I had to use this for the wacky wikipedia /Special: syntax in [Roadkill wiki](http://roadkill.codeplex.com) . Hanselman goes into some detail here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: it fails for me under IIS express (version 8) and .NET 4.5

Comment: We had a similar issue (url contained an Id with a dot):
/example/id/123.45

By adding a trailing slash to the url it worked for us:
/example/id/12345/

Answer (score 8):

Everything after the '.' is the file extension.  If that extension isn't mapped to ASP.NET, it won't get handed off to the ASP.NET handler.  IIS looks for a static file instead.  Hence the 404.  If it doesn't add anything (and hard to see how it would), I suggest stripping it out.

Comment: But it also happens in the visual studio web server, where all the request are mapped to asp.net. It must be a previous handler or a security mesure. Even the static file requests pass through my handlers. But if the request has a "./" in any position it's a no no

Comment: I don't think you can make any reasonable inferences from how the development server behaves.  For all we know, it knows about this problem with IIS and is doing its best to behave the same way.  In the end, it doesn't matter, because you're going to deploy with IIS, not Cassini.

Answer (score 1):

When the trailing period is not significant (as it is in the case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etc.) you can use IIS's URL Rewrite module to strip the trailing periods.

**Pattern**: `^(.*[^.])(\.+)$`
**Rewrite URL:** `{R:1}`

This isn't going to help when throwing away the period is not an option, or there are periods at the end of intermediate path segments, but for the very real use case of dealing with periods being tacked on to URLs by auto-linking algorithms it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IIS might not know how to handle a request with an empty extension.

Right click on the website and choose "Properties".
Click "Configuration..." on the "Home Directory" tab.
Look at the "Application Extensions" and try adding an empty or wildcard extension.

Comment: I don't think so, it also happen in the visual studio web server, where all the extensions are managed by the .net handler. in my case the url is like http://search.com/search/search-term-with-dot./location.aspx

Comment: Hmm if you get the error in VS as well are you sure you don't have an ignore route that is getting hit?

Comment: while debugging it, the request doesn't hit the breakpoint in the routin engine. if you see the links that i posted in the comment to stefan, the treatment of both request is very diferent, one is handled by the 404 registered handler, and the another one by the default one.

Answer (score -2):

In windows, file names cannot end with a '.'
I think all problems stem from there, ie IIS doesn't know what to do with it, so it never gets as far as the ASP.NET error handler and gets handles by the default IIS 404 page.

Most search engines ([well Google anyway](http://www.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=430)) exclude punctuation from queries, and I think yours should too.

EDIT:
It falls over because it has no file type, even the Microsoft site falls over look http://www.microsoft.com/en/us/fallover. but you can modify the default error files (live somewhere like C:\WINDOWS\help\iisHelp\common) or change it completely.

Check this one out: [Configuring Custom Error Messages (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Surely, file names can end with '.' in Windows.

Comment: Not true, and the routing system in ASP.NET has nothing to do with file names.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't be putting exact user searches in the query string like that... you should UrlEncode them. That will solve the problem.

Comment: the dot is a valid character in the url, so if I urlencode something with a dot it will remain the same.

Comment: would not, take a look at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net%2E