# ASP.NET MVC: How to Route Search Term with . (Period) at the end

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, routes, period, asp.net-mvc

I get a 404 response from .Net MVC when I try to make a request where my search term ends with a `.` (period). This is the route that I'm using:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Json",
                "Remote.mvc/{action}/{searchTerm}/{count}",
                new { controller="Remote", count=10}
            );
```

The search works fine with a `.` inside the search term, it just cannot end with it.  Any thoughts on how to route this search request?

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net#328873

Answer (score 25):

I have solved a similar issue (I had trouble with paths like /music/R.E.M.)
I've added the following line into the system.webServer/handlers section (adjusted for your case):

```
 <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="Remote.mvc/*" verb="GET"/>
```

I've noted also, that

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

does work only if the period (.) is somewhere in the middle pair of slashes (e.g. /abc/d.e/f) and does not work when the period looks like a file type separator (e.g. /abc/de/f.g).

Comment: Out of all the answers I found, yours was the only one that addressed my need exactly. Thank you.

Comment: does this need to be the only handler?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can set this flag in the system.web section of your web.config and it will be allowed:

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

I've tested it and it works. [Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) has an explanation of it.

Comment: As mentioned by Kosau, it only works if the period (.) is somewhere in the middle pair of slashes (e.g. /abc/d.e/f) and does not work when the period looks like a file type separator (e.g. /abc/de/f.g).