# ASP.NET MVC Route IDs with a period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

If I have a route with the following:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

I look at the following URL:

```
c1/a1/abc.
```

It doesn't work. 
This only happens when the period is at the end of the URL.
Any way to get ASP.NET MVC to recognize that as part of the ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the answers to the two similar problems below, I only can suggest that you encode the period before passing it to you MVC application. It looks as the period is also treated as a delimter to a rule succh as "/".

Similar problem here:

- [Semantic urls with dots in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net)
- [ASP.NET MVC: How to Route Search Term with . (Period) at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332757/asp-net-mvc-how-to-route-search-term-with-period-at-the-end)

Answer (score 12):

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can set this flag in your web.config and it will be allowed:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

I've tested it and it works. [Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) has an explanation of it.

Comment: Phew, that was a real lifer saver!

Comment: This was the only method I found to work on MVC4

Comment: Thank you. I tried 5 different answers that I found on SO. This was the only technique I found that worked.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Worked for me 12 years later for ASP Net Core 3.1