# Trailing dot in MVC 5 WebRequest URL causes 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, url, http-status-code-404

I am running `MVC 5` and have a search API that produces the following link: `/SearchedItem.?format=json` where `SearchedItem.` is the user's input into search. This obviously causes a famous 404 due to a `dot` character. I've looked into all of the following solutions:

[Dot character '.' in MVC Web API 2 for request such as api/people/STAFF.45287](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287)

[Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728846/dots-in-url-causes-404-with-asp-net-mvc-and-iis)

[ApiController returns 404 when ID contains period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298542/apicontroller-returns-404-when-id-contains-period)

However, neither adding a slash (tried both `/SearchedItem./?format=json` and `/SearchedItem.?format=json/`) nor `RAMMFAR` worked.

Looking for any new suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your web.config, the trailing dot let's iis think you are accessing an image.

Add the following within the system.webServer / handlers ( web.config)

```
<add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0"
 path="/api/*"
 verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
 type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
 preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Another suggest would be to set RunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true, but i wouldn't recommend that. All static assets would be handled through the .net code then :)

I see in your question that you checked related links. But are you sure? Because i have came accross this in the past and above was my solution...

Comment: I believe MVC 5 is the problem

Comment: MVC 5 is a framework on top of Asp.Net... Do you have something more?

Comment: Solutions listed in my questions fail under MVC 5, people confirm that within answer comments.

Comment: Did you change your project from MVC 4 to MVC 5 and used the walkthrough given at : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2?

Comment: No, the project has originally been written using MVC 5

Answer (score 0):

Most suitable way is to encode once you route to url and decode in the respective action you can use HttpUtility to perform encoding and decoding

If you don't want to encode and decode then try adding relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping config as explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310187/asp-net-mvc-route-ids-with-a-period)