# ASP.NET URL contains multi "dot" symbol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, web-config, url-routing, system.web.routing

I wrote the code in global.asax contain this

```
oRoutes.MapPageRoute("test-route", "home/{cURL}", "~/test.aspx");
```

everything fine, but had error when URL contains "." symbol. And I add the code below just can fix only one dot in URL.

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

For Example, when I call http://foo.com/home/open.door.foo/, the routing failed.

Is there any simple way to fix this problem? thanks.

P.S 1: please don't provide the way to remove last words like ".foo", because there could be occur in my URL like http://foo.com/hey.john.open.the.book.volume.1-brabra :-)

P.S 2: For some reason, I must be use "." symbol in URL. :'(

Comment: I just tested in an MVC3 app.. it works fine.

Comment: I can do that on IIS7.5 + .NET 4.0 + Web Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess based on several posts here in SO, you should encode your values

[ASP.NET MVC: How to Route Search Term with . (Period) at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332757/asp-net-mvc-how-to-route-search-term-with-period-at-the-end)

[Semantic urls with dots in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net#328873)

Comment: I had read those post that you pasted before ask this question. But I have some reasons can't replace this "." symbol, sorry...