# Allow Route IDs with multiple periods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I allow multiple periods in a URL?

Sample URL:

`http://mylocalhost:6968/MyHome/Edit/ABCD.Applications.ClinicalData%257cCache_Timeout`

I have tried:

**Various Url Encoding:**

```
       @{
            //string encodedItem = Url.Encode(item.Key);
            //string encodedItem = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Key);                
            string encodedItem = Server.UrlEncode(item.Key);
        }
```

**[Adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332757/asp-net-mvc-how-to-route-search-term-with-period-at-the-end) a route handler:**

```
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="Remote.mvc/*" verb="GET"/>
```

**[Modifying](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx) the web.config `system.web`**

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
```

None of these things corrected the example URL.

**Relevant code**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Key)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                //string encodedItem = Url.Encode(item.Key);
                //string encodedItem = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Key);                
                string encodedItem = Server.UrlEncode(item.Key);                
            }
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id = encodedItem }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {  id = encodedItem }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {  id = encodedItem })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I'm clicking the Edit link.

I also tried

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id = item.Key })`

which had the html output of:

`a href=/MyHome/Edit/ABCD.Applications.ClinicalData%7CCache_Timeout`

Click this link results in Error:

`HTTP Error 404.0`

I set a breakpoint in `Controller.Edit`.  The breakpoint is never hit.  Anytime I have a url of the form:

`http://mylocalhost:6968/MyHome/Edit/ABCD.X`

Where X is anything after a `.` then this error occurs.  If I remove X, the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Which Url.encode is that? Is it HttpUtility.UrlEncode or HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode ? HttpUtility.UrlEncode seems to handle punctuation in query parameters / path portion of url. Check out the documentation/Remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook - Question updated.

Comment: How are you using the URL that it is getting messed up? What if you instead built up the final url using the Uri class? For example: Uri uri = new Uri("http://mylocalhost:6968/MyHome/Edit/ABCD.Applications.ClinicalData%257cCache_Timeout");

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook - `item.key` comes from the `Model` which comes from a value in the DB.  I'll insert the relevant code as well.

Comment: Have you tried `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Key })`? If yes, what was the rendered `href` attribute and what was the result when you clicked on this anchor (did you get an error, if yes please specify what error did you get)?

Comment: @StevenMagana-Zook Try what Darin suggests, it might be that MVC4 already encodes/decodes this on your behalf.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP GET proved impossible.  I decided to redesign the solution.  Now I perform an **HTTP POST** in order to avoid passing data via the URL.

Ideally, my URL's would be [hackable](http://2002-2012.mattwilcox.net/archive/entry/id/990/).  But its an internal app and its what the customer wants so...hey kid, be careful broken glass