# ASP.NET MVC Route Value ID with Period

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 web application where some ID's can contain the period character.

For example

This works fine
http://www.website.com/Employee/Details/123

This will fail
http://www.website.com/Employee/Details/123.45

But this will work fine
http://www.website.com/Employee/Details/?id=123.45

Similar problem here:

- [Semantic urls with dots in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net)
- [ASP.NET MVC: How to Route Search Term with . (Period) at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332757/asp-net-mvc-how-to-route-search-term-with-period-at-the-end)

Currently all the solutions I have found are described in the links above.

1. `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />`
2. `<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" path="Remote.mvc/*" verb="GET"/>`

As users will only browse to these url's via menus and link in the web page, I was hoping that the ActionLink html helper could be smart enough to render the ?id=123.45 when it recognizes the Id contains unsafe characters for the the Id route value.

Or is there a way to force the ActionLink html helper to always render the Id route value in the query string?

**Update**
I could not find any parameters to force ActionLink to render the ?id= query string parameter so I found 2 possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

Create an html helper to generate the url.
Any comments for improvement on this code would be appreciated.

```
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkSafeId(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {

        var routeValuesDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
        MvcHtmlString link = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
        if (routeValuesDictionary.ContainsKey("id") && routeValuesDictionary["id"].ToString().Contains('.'))
        {
            if (routeValuesDictionary.Count == 1)
            {
                var searchValue = string.Format("/{0}", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
                var replaceValue = string.Format("?id={0}", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
                link = new MvcHtmlString(link.ToString().Replace(searchValue, replaceValue));
            }
            else
            {
                var searchValue = string.Format("/{0}?", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
                var replaceValue = string.Format("?id={0}&", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
                link = new MvcHtmlString(link.ToString().Replace(searchValue, replaceValue));
            }
        }

        return link;
    }
```

**Solution 2**

Disable the use of id route value in your route configuration.
This can either be done for the default route, a specific controller or a specific controller/action.

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another easy solution would be to add a trailing /

As you said, this will not work:
http://www.website.com/Employee/Details/123.45
But this will:
http://www.website.com/Employee/Details/123.45/

I assume the reason for this is that IIS is trying to interpret everything after the dot as an extension. By adding a / you are indicating that this is not supposed to be treated this way.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, for a WebAPI project I'm working on. Your solution worked perfectly. But, WOW, I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks, @Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

Update I could not find any parameters to force ActionLink to render the ?id= query string parameter so I found 2 possible solutions.

Solution 1

Create an html helper to generate the url. Any comments for improvement on this code would be appreciated.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkSafeId(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{

    var routeValuesDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
    MvcHtmlString link = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    if (routeValuesDictionary.ContainsKey("id") && routeValuesDictionary["id"].ToString().Contains('.'))
    {
        if (routeValuesDictionary.Count == 1)
        {
            var searchValue = string.Format("/{0}", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
            var replaceValue = string.Format("?id={0}", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
            link = new MvcHtmlString(link.ToString().Replace(searchValue, replaceValue));
        }
        else
        {
            var searchValue = string.Format("/{0}?", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
            var replaceValue = string.Format("?id={0}&", routeValuesDictionary["id"]);
            link = new MvcHtmlString(link.ToString().Replace(searchValue, replaceValue));
        }
    }

    return link;
}
```

Solution 2

Disable the use of id route value in your route configuration. This can either be done for the default route, a specific controller or a specific controller/action.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
    );
```