# ASP.NET MVC Routing vs. Reserved Filenames in Windows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis

In our ASP.NET MVC application, we've noticed that we cannot have The Forbidden DOS File Names—`COM1` through `COM9`, `LPT1` through `LPT9`, `CON`, `AUX`, `PRN`, and `NUL`—anywhere in our routes.  They inevitably result in IIS telling us the file cannot be found, even when we set routing not to check for the existence of files first.  How can we work around this?

Comment: For fun, hit http://stackoverflow.com/com1 and compare to http://stackoverflow.com/ThisDoesNotExist

Comment: interestingly, stackoverflow.com/clock$ works fine, even though CLOCK$ is a reserved device filename as well.

Comment: And leveraging this knowledge, I have now successfully made it impossible to navigate to my user page.  Woot.

Comment: I like how you DOS'd yourself.

Comment: Very cool; but not impossible - the username isn't required in the user info route ;)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/com1.aspx ))

Comment: I was wondering why when someone added a tag for "con" (short for convention, as in comic-con) on my site I couldn't get to tags/con. +1 to both this Q and the A.

Comment: Ran into this problem again... but found that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987105/asp-net-mvc-routing-vs-reserved-filenames-in-windows/2746438#2746438 was the correct solution.  Think that the accepted answer could be changed/updated?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This has been addressed in ASP.NET 4. http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

You can apply a setting in web.config that relaxes this restriction.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

    <!-- ... your other settings ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @thekaid: Backwards compatibility: MS cannot be certain no-one depends on the old behaviour.

Comment: @thekaido What Richard said is exactly right. You'd be surprised at the types of bugs people start to rely on.

Answer (score 18):

Since asking the question, I've found that the bug is in ASP.NET proper, not IIS or ASP.NET MVC, meaning that there's no way to work around it.  The only solution is to manually forbid URLs matching these names and these names followed by a period and random characters.

Comment: Yup. :)  The ASP.NET team is aware of this bug and is looking into it for ASP.NET 4.  Can't guarantee if it will be fixed, but at least there is interest in making this better for developers.

Answer (score 4):

For a similar reason, there can't be a `web.config` tag in StackOverflow.

http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/98871-web-config-tag-404-error

Answer (score 0):

for another similar reason you can't have urls with a dot and a slash 
[Semantic urls with dots in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net)