# MVC3 404 for any URL containing "PRN"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7.5

I have run into a strange issue where any URL containing "PRN" will return a 404.

If I have 2 methods:

```
    public string Test(string x)
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    public string PRN(string x)
    {
        return "worked";
    }
```

I can call test by navigating to:
Controller/Test

It will always return "hello."  However, if I try to call:
Controller/Test/PRN, I get a 404

If I attempt to call Controller/PRN/Anything, I get a 404

In multiple MVC3 applications, I have found that any URL containing "PRN" will return a 404 error.  Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
This is my route configuration:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );

    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your routes configuration

Comment: Might be worth posting your RegisterRoutes contents as this is the most likely candidate for issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a read a this : http://bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/

Which points to : [ASP.NET MVC Routing vs. Reserved Filenames in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987105/asp-net-mvc-routing-vs-reserved-filenames-in-windows)

Answer (score -1):

If you call `Controller/Test/PRN' It wont point to anything because you are calling the`Test` ActionMethod and passing PRN as the parameter.

Try adding ...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "PRN", // Route name
            "Controller/PRN/{x}", // URL with parameters
            new { x = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

... to the top of your `RegisterRoutes` method in Global.asax.cs folder.

Comment: I understand that, but "PRN" should work fine as a parameter.  If I call Controller/Test/SomethingThatIsntPRN, it returns "hello" as I would expect.