# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing issue in Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a very strange routing issue.

I have a ASP.NET MVC 3 site using areas.
I have the following routes setup in the Assets Area:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        null,
        "Assets/{controller}/{action}/{code}",
        null,
        new { code = @"(\w{2,3}$)" }
    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "Assets_default",
        "Assets/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

When I request the following URLs it works perfectly

```
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/AEP
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/MEC
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/GP
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/BR2 
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/ZZZ 
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/123
```

But when I requests this URL I get a "404 - resource can't be found" error

```
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/PRN
http://site.com/Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/prn
```

Every other URL I've tried works - it seems to be just PRN that has issues.

I've put a break point at the beginning of the GalleriesController > GetByCode action, and the PRN route doesn't even try to enter the action (as the 404 error suggests).

Does anyone have any ideas why PRN doesn't work in the route? Or what else I can try to investigate?

Thanks for your help
Saan

Comment: does your `Index` action get hit instead?

Comment: Have you tried removing the regex restraint on the route? Have you also tried putting the parameters in the same order as they are in the default route?

Comment: Yep, tried hard coding a constraint of context.MapRoute(null, "Assets/Gallery/GetByCode/PRN", new {controller="Gallery", action="GetByCode", code="PRN" ); and it still didn't work

Comment: Woah. That's weird. No idea whats going on there! Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be related to the fact that you can't create the folder "prn" on the Windows file system. My guess is IIS uses the windows file system in such a way that this issue resonates to the described problem above.

In fact, this post may help you: [ASP.NET MVC Routing vs. Reserved Filenames in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987105/asp-net-mvc-routing-vs-reserved-filenames-in-windows)