# URL Rewriting not working with URL ending ".ad" or ".cd"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, url-rewriting

I'm having some difficulties with my custom URL-rewriting setup. I'm not using any 3rd party tool to manage this, just using the global.asax by looking at every request and processing it.

The way I am using it is like:
**www.mydomain.com/site/google.com**

This page contains information about the site "google.com". I'm using the actual domain within the URL. This is all works fine.

I have simplified the code that I'm using just to show you an example of how it works:

```
Dim myContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
Dim URL As String = myContext.Request.ServerVariables("URL")
If URL.ToLower.Contains("/site/") Then
    URL = URL.Trim("/")
    Dim strURL As String = URL.ToLower.Split("/")(1)
    Redirect301("/site.aspx?url=" & strURL)
    Exit Sub
End If
```

The issue I'm having is for certain domain extensions, the page will just load up custom 404 Not Found and I have no idea what the cause is.

Example of pages that don't load:

- /site/google.ad
- /site/google.cd

I'm guessing that the system thinks that .cd and .ad files are actual physical files and when it doesn't find them, it shows the custom 404 error. It doesn't actually looks like the request is getting through to the global.asax. When working in local environment, they actually load fine but only on the live server it has this issue and this is why it has been a nightmare trying to figure it out.

Another issue I found was loading the following URL:

- /site/prn.com

This shows a 404 error again but this time not the custom one I created but the actual hard looking .net 404 error page. This also works fine in local environment.

There must be some IIS setting or code change I could do to try to get this resolved.

Thank you for your time :)

Aki

Comment: Does IIS have those extensions as MIMEs?

Comment: I think the Application.config for IIS blocks those extensions.  Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

Comment: That fixed the problem with the .cd & .ad extentions but do you have any ideas on why the /site/prn.com would show a hard 404 error:

"The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. "

Comment: And this extension goes through Global.asax routing?

Comment: Yes it works fine on all other formats. For some reason just the /site/prn.com does this. For example, /site/rn.com works fine. It also works fine locally. it doesn't look like its hitting the global.asax at all though. It can't be anything to do with the extension this time. Very odd.

Comment: This is the error of the 404 page:
"[HttpException]
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection.GetSettings(HttpContext context, Boolean canThrow)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.ReportRuntimeError(Exception e, Boolean canThrow, Boolean localExecute)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.ReportRuntimeErrorIfExists(RequestNotificationStatus& status)". It does look like it's treating it as a physical file..

Comment: Since it's a .com extension , it would ideally treat it as a website and not a resource , now since you say the issue is only for prn.com , you can check the host file i.e. C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and see if by any chance prm.com is mapped to some other resource altogether

Comment: The file is empty. Out of thousands of pages I have, this one seems to be the only one suffering from this.

Comment: Maybe you could post a new question , if someone else could help ... I seem to be out of ideas . sorry

Comment: I found the fix for anyone having same issue: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987105/asp-net-mvc-routing-vs-reserved-filenames-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link . [Error message when you try to browse a Web page that is hosted on IIS 7.0: "HTTP Error 404.7 – FILE_EXTENSION_DENIED](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942045)

This is the reason .ad .cd extensions are blocked.

Comment: Quick response and a great answer. I knew it had to do with some sort of IIS setting :).

The problem I have left is the /site/prn.com  still shows the hard 404 error. Any ideas?