# Allow CON, reserved keywords in URLs

Tags: c#, .net, iis, url

I need to allow URL's that have some reserved keywords like CON, AUX, NUL etc in the URL Names eg: ..../CON/...

Right now I get a 404 Error and the following exception when I try to go to such an URL:

```
[HttpException]
   at System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData()
```

This has been fixed for .Net 4 according to other posts on this site [Semantic urls with dots in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net) , I however cannot upgrade to .Net4 due to other dependencies so need an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: I'm missing something here.  URLs don't have reserved keywords.  And I can't find CachedPathData or GetConfigPathData anywhere in MSDN.

Comment: @yodaj007 They have special meaning in Windows as they are devices.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft's response to this on connect and MSDN forums, there is no workaround in asp.net other than upgrading to 4.0.   You could try using IIS url rewriting, but you still can't actually put COM1 (or whatever) in your routes.

(See also: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx)

Comment: links to "connect and MSDN forums" would make this a more useful answer.

Comment: @Ian will edit when I can. the perils of posting from a phone include not having the patience re-research on a 3" screen over slow connection.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET 4 fixes this issue with a new setting. In web.config, simply add 
  `<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>` to the system.web node. Here’s a snippet from my web.config.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
<!-- ... your other settings ... -->
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: See http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/

Comment: I'm running web APIs under .NET 4.7.2 and this does not do anything. The only way I can pass in a user email that has 'con' in it is if I surround the email in quotes i.e. 'con.xx@xxx.com' Any clue how else to derestrict this keyword in 4.7.2?