# asp.net mvc 3 url end with a "." and throws a 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, http-status-code-404

I have a asp.net mvc 3 application and I want the users to be able to enter in tags of sorts.  However, when a tag ends with a "." (no quotes) it throws a 404 before hitting the controller's method.

Any ideas...? Is this common or something jacked up with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was already asked and answered.  It is a silly MS thing.

[Semantic urls with dots in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294495/semantic-urls-with-dots-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

I think IIS is throwing the 404 before control gets to your application. I suspect it's matching the ExpressionlessURLHandler for the path `*.`.

If you are brave, I suppose you could change the handler for that path to be asp, but I suspect there are some security implications to allowing that path through to asp.

Perhaps use a different character?